# Java - fill in specific indices for a byte array

Tags: java, arrays

Suppose I have a byte array with 65 indices, and I want to fill the first 62 indices (or bytes) with data since index 63-65 are reserved. How can I move a byte array to the first 62 indices of the byte array?

```
String message = "Hello to the client. This is the message that you will receive"; //62 bytes message
byte[] b = message.getBytes();

byte[] sendData = new byte[65];
//how can I transfer byte[] b to 0-62?
```

Comment: There is no such thing as a 62 bytes message, because `getBytes` depends on an encoding. Can you be sure that 62 bytes will always be enough?

Comment: I checked if it was 62 bytes by running b.length.

Comment: I know, but that result is platform-dependent. See the docs for `String.getBytes`.

Answer (score 1):

Loop through the 62 indeces (0-61 btw) and copy the cells.

```
for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
    sendData[i] = b[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you're getting at, but I think the `Arrays.copy` method will help you. With this method, you can copy certain parts of an array to other arrays, saving the sections you're concerned about.